# OpenVPN L2 QNAP - How to create a VPN in the same subnet?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, nas, qnap

Setting up QNAP's OpenVPN server. With normal configuration VPN client get an IP from VPN pool, in the VPN subnet. I need clients to get an IP from LAN pool, in the LAN subnet.

Any suggestions?

Tks!

Comment: Why need a vpn connect if your device are in a same subnet?

Comment: The have upnp through VPN...